# Trying to add custom fields to title

Tags: php

Wrote some php code for my site to add custom fields to titles, but when I add it I get syntax error and it breaks my site.

```
add_filter( 'pt_cv_fields_html', 'cvp_theme_other_fields_in_title', 100, 2 );
function cvp_theme_other_fields_in_title( $args, $post ) {
    global $pt_cv_id;
    if ( in_array( $pt_cv_id, array( 'e3cd1844un', '60d308bw40' ) ) ) {
        if ( isset( $args[ 'custom-fields' ] ) ) {
            $args[ 'title' ] .= " " . strip_tags( $args[ 'custom-fields' ] );
            unset( $args[ 'custom-fields' ] );
        }
    }
    return $args;
}
```

Scratching my head here as I'm quite new to php. Can't see what I am doing wrong.

Comment: share your error please

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there was no error in the actual code, but I had forgotten to add an ending // in the comment field.